# spring cloud contract artifactory apikey

Tags: spring-boot, artifactory, api-key, spring-cloud-contract

I'm using spring cloud contract verifier in a gradle project.

My contracts are in a sparate repository published in artifactory.
So I use REMOTE as value of contractMode.

Our artfactory doesnt support user/password authentication.
We can only use artifactory apikey.

So we pass the artifactory api key as value of the http header X-JFrog-Art-Api. This works for download gradle "normal" dependencies.
Unfortunately spring cloud contract dependency management does not rely on gradle authentication.

So we are getting this errors in our builds:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact com.mycompany:myservice-artifactid:jar:stubs:0.0.5 in remote0 (https://artifactoryUrl.com/maven-virtual)
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:423)
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:225)
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:202)
    at shaded.org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:257)
    at org.springframework.cloud.contract.stubrunner.AetherStubDownloader.unpackedJar(AetherStubDownloader.java:185)
    ... 211 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact com.mycompany:myservice-artifactid:jar:stubs:0.0.5 in remote0 (https://artifactoryUrl.com/maven-virtual)
```

Is there a way to use an artifactory api key with spring cloud contract ?

here my config

In the plugin section

```
plugins {
....
    id "org.springframework.cloud.contract" version "2.2.2.RELEASE"
}
```

The contract dsl configuration :

```
contracts {
    testFramework = TestFramework.JUNIT5
    contractRepository {
        repositoryUrl = artifactoryRepoUrl
    }
    contractDependency {
        stringNotation = 'com.mycompany:myservice-artifactid:0.0.5'
    }
    contractsPath =  "contracts"
    contractsMode = "REMOTE"
    baseClassForTests "com.mycompany.myservice.ServiceRestBase"
}
```

Comment: how are you using API Key? Where exactly you are passing the API key during the build? Also the error says that it could not find the artifact, are you looking for the correct artifact?

Comment: @MuhammedKashif the artifact really exists in artifactory. but spring cloud contrat cannot download it from artifactory because of authentication issue. 


My original question is : How can I use API Key ?

Comment: If REST APIs are being used, you can pass the API key with the help of this header X-JFrog-Art-Api. If not, you can pass it as a normal username and password in the credential

Comment: @MuhammedKashif that's exactly the question I'm asking. How to use header  X-JFrog-Art-Api with spring cloud contract ?